# Edit item in all frames of a timeline layer in Flash CS5

Tags: flash, symbols, frames, timeline, flash-cs5

I'm confused as to how Flash CS5 treats symbol instances across different frames in a given layer; If I add an object to a layer, and then add a keyframe to the existing frame set, are there now two instances of the object, one for each frame?  When I change the color of the instance in the first key frame, the second keyframes instance stays the same.  Is there anyway to edit across all frames?  Paste across all frames?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following is *object* the same as an *instance*. Actually an *object* is the *instance* of a *symbol* or *class*.

> If I add an object to a layer, and then add a keyframe to the existing frame set, are there now two instances of the object, one for each frame?

You look at key frames separately. In both frames there is one instance each. If both instances have the same *instance name*, you can say that they are identical, although the actual instance parameters of them can completely differ (like size, position, color, effects etc.).

> When I change the color of the instance in the first key frame, the second keyframes instance stays the same. Is there anyway to edit across all frames? Paste across all frames?

When you are editing an instance's color, or in general its instance parameters, you only affect the current instance you are editing. Even if two instance's have the same instance name, they are completely different objects and both have independent instance parameters.

If you want to share things across multiple instances you can either modify the symbol itself (which changes *all* instances) or you could wrap a symbol's instance in another symbol which you then instanciate multiple times. The first symbol's instance parameters then can be changed and apply to all instances of the second symbol.

Comment: Poke, thanks but some of your explanation is unclear- If instances across frames have the same name but different properties, then HOW are they identical?

Comment: Also, could you clarify what you mean in the last paragraph?

Comment: @Yarin, regarding the first: They are treated as identical in code; for example when you add listeners or such to them, those listeners will work on all keyframes where the instance name is the same. Also the different properties apply to different times (it's like having a blue ball first and then painting it red, it's still the "same" ball; although Flash will have two different instances for it as the red ball is in a different time/keyframe).

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph I tried to explain that you can cascade multiple symbols and instances. Let's say you have symbol A and want to share the same properties across multiple frames. You usually create instances A1, A2, A3 etc., but when you later change A1's properties, A2 and A3 are uneffected. Instead you could put A1 into a new symbol B, instanciate that three times (B1, B2, B3) and when you decide you want to make changes, you change A1 inside of the symbol B and it carries over all instances of B. So B is just a cascaded holder for an instance of A that is used multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, make your changes prior to making the keyframes, or copy the item that is modified, and paste and replace it in the subsequent frames.